# Handling session time out when ajax call to C# mvc controller not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session-timeout

When calling a function from ajax. Program flow does not recognized the expired session i.e not redirect to the login page. Instead of that, it saves the record. I am working in c# .net mvc. So how can i handle session while ajax call. Here i gave my codes.

```
 $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST",
            url:'/Employee/SaveEmployee',
            data:
            {
                Location:$("#txtLocation").val(), 
                dateApplied:$("#txtDateApplied").val(), 
                Status:$("#ddStatus").val(), 
                mailCheck:$("#ddMailCheck").val(),
                ...
                ...
                ... 
            },
            success: function (result) 
            {

            },
            error: function (msg) 
            {
            }
      });
```

Here the controller

```
[Authorize]
public string SaveEmployee(string Location, string dateApplied, string Status, string mailCheck, ...)
{
      objEmpMain.FirstName = firstName;
      objEmpMain.LastName = lastName;
      objEmpMain.Initial = Initial;
      objEmpMain.Address1 = Address;
      ...
      ... 
      ...
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The result of your AJAX call will still likely end up appearing successful (although, don't worry, it won't actually execute your action method), and invoke your `success` handler. This is because you are expecting HTML, and that is what you are receiving (albeit, the resulting HTML is likely your login page, and not the HTML you wanted). As an aside, if you expected JSON (using `dataType:'JSON'`), it would trigger an error, because it would be parsing HTML as JSON.

What you need to do is prevent FormsAuth from redirecting the login page for AJAX requests. Now, `AuthorizeAttribute` faithfully returns a `NotAuthorizedResult`, which sends an HTTP 401 Not Authorized response to the client, which is ideal for your AJAX client.

The problem is that FormsAuth module checks the StatusCode and if it is 401, it performs the redirect. I've combatted this issue in this way:

1) Create my own derivative type of `AuthorizeAttribute` that places a flag  in`HttpContext.Items` to let me know authorization failed, and I should force a 401 rather than a redirect:

```
public class AjaxAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Processes HTTP requests that fail authorization.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filterContext">Encapsulates the information for using <see cref="T:System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute"/>. The <paramref name="filterContext"/> object contains the controller, HTTP context, request context, action result, and route data.</param>
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest()) filterContext.HttpContext.Items["AjaxPermissionDenied"] = true;

        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }
}
```

2) Add to your Global.asax.cs:

```
    protected void Application_EndRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Context.Items["AjaxPermissionDenied"] is bool)
        {
            Context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
            Context.Response.End();
        }
     }
```

3) Add a statusCode handler to your jQuery AJAX setup:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    statusCode: {
        401: function() {
            window.location.href = "path/to/login";
        }
    }
});
```

4) Change the controllers or actions where you want this behavior from using `AuthorizeAttribute` to `AjaxAuthorizeAttribute`:

```
[AjaxAuthorize]
public string SaveEmployee(string Location, string dateApplied, string Status, string mailCheck, ...)
{
      objEmpMain.FirstName = firstName;
      objEmpMain.LastName = lastName;
      objEmpMain.Initial = Initial;
      objEmpMain.Address1 = Address;
      ...
      ... 
      ...
}
```

Comment: Actually my present class looks like following "public class EmployeeController : Controller". Are you instruct me to change like following "public class AjaxAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute" ????

Comment: Just swap out `AuthorizeAttribute` for `AjaxAuthorizeAttribute` that you decorated on your controllers or controller actions. See #4 which I just added.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain me where i need to create the "public class AjaxAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute" class???

Comment: And for your information already i handled the session time out. But it works for the function call from view. But only the ajax call is the major problem.

Comment: You would create it anywhere in your MVC project, or in any project in your solution that the MVC application references. For example, you could place it right in the root of the MVC project.

Comment: Your instructed codes working well.. but the redirection alone is the problem for me. Where i can write ajax setup function?

Comment: Dude.. i tested the "HttpContext.Response.StatusCode.ToString();" it gives us 200 as result. :(

Comment: @HackedByChinese - your solution works great. Just a follow-up question - why do you call Context.Response.End() in Application_EndRequest?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to sugguest you to use StatusCode = 306.
I met some problem when use 401.IIS treat 401 different from what I understand.
306 works fine for me.

Regards.