# jquery $.ajaxSetup() handle ajax errors

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I would like to add (default) action when an error occurs and it's not (403, 500 or 410 code):

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
        statusCode: {
            403: function () {
                window.location = '@Url.Action("LogOn", "Account", new {area = "", msg = "forbidden", returnUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl})' + window.location.hash;
            },
            500: function() {
                window.location = '@Url.Action("AccessDenied", "Error")';
            },
            410: function() {
                window.location = '@Url.Action("Deleted", "Error")';
            }
            // ANY OTHER ERROR CODE - but it doesn't work, how can i do it?
            if not any above and it's an error then =>
            window.location = '@Url.Action("Index", "Error")';
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using [`ajaxError()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) to handle errors **not** `ajaxSetup()`:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, xhr, options) {
     switch (xhr.status)
     {
        case 403:
            window.location = '@Url.Action("LogOn", "Account", new {area = "", msg = "forbidden", returnUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl})' + window.location.hash;
        break;
        case 500:
            window.location = '@Url.Action("AccessDenied", "Error")';
        break;
        case 410:
            window.location = '@Url.Action("Deleted", "Error")';
        break;
        default:
            window.location = '@Url.Action("Index", "Error")';
        break;
     }
   }
});
```

Comment: but for some reason using ajaxError hit that function: please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080462/handling-session-timeout-in-ajax

Comment: but still. ajaxError for some reason is never hit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16080462/handling-session-timeout-in-ajax

Comment: @ShaneKm Did you try attaching it to `$(document)` like in my answer and not `$("body")` like in your question.

Comment: yes. i never get alert(IN) response. is it something wrong with my attribute? but as you can see in firebug response I do get the right response

Comment: I don't know, your function takes 4 parameters, the one I specify takes 3 (that's the one I use). Have you tried changing that?

Answer (score 0):

The "complete" event is always fired .

```
complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    switch (jqXHR.status) {
        case 200:
            alert("error 200");
            break;
        case 404:
            alert("error 404");
            break;
        default:
            alert("DEFAULT");
    }
}
```